# C# printing Issues

Tags: c#, .net

```
    private void printReceipt()
    {
        printDialog.Document = printDocument;

        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result != DialogResult.OK) return;
        try
        {
            sPrint = new StreamReader(
                     new MemoryStream(
                         Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(richTextBoxResult.Text)));

            printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument_PrintPage);

            printDocument.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to print \n" + e.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            if (sPrint != null)
                sPrint.Close();
        }
    }

    void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // No of lines that fit on to the page
        float linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / richTextBoxResult.Font.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        float fontHeight = richTextBoxResult.Font.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        for (int count = 0; count < linesPerPage && !sPrint.EndOfStream; count++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sPrint.ReadLine(),
                richTextBoxResult.Font,
                Brushes.Black,
                e.MarginBounds.Left,
                e.MarginBounds.Top + (count * fontHeight),
                new StringFormat());
        }
        e.HasMorePages = !sPrint.EndOfStream;          

    }
```

My questions:-

1. I need to fit all textbox content correctly when I print. (Lengthy single row not printed, rather jumped outside of the page)
2. Are there any possibilities to enable print range option under print Menu? (On output GUI, Let's say i have text content which can fit on more than one page)

Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you thought about using reports? Give a little more work to implement but must meet what you want.

Comment: Getting rich text to print correctly requires hocus pocus.  But well documented in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425)

Comment: Any particular reason for using __ASCII__ encoding? Seems a waste to throw away Unicode support. And you can eliminate whole issue and the MemoryStream by using a StringReader.

Answer (score 0):

As for your string going out of bounds when printing, use [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as you're doing now, but with different parameters. Graphics.DrawString has a different set of parameters which let you define a height and width of a rectangle in which your string must fit. If you give this the proper width, the string will be 'broken off' when the last word on thesame line won't fit and start a newline.

Like this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(sPrint.ReadLine(),
            richTextBoxResult.Font,
            Brushes.Black,
            new RectangleF(x, y, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
```

Remark on the above code, it might not be a good idea to hard code the limits of your page, but you get the idea.

As for your second question, if I understand it correctly: you want to measure at which point your string won't fit on your page (vertically)? You can use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for that. I've been struggling with thesame thing, and I've found this to be one of the more performant options.